# Image In Crystal Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

i use asp.net with c# and Display Image In Crystal Report 
The Image is display well when data display on report
but when no data  available then image is also not display.

i use dataset to bind data source 
in dataset there are two tables 
first which is contain image byte stream and second with Actual data of Report.

problem is that

when second table have data then Image is Display well on report
but when Second table have no data then Image is not Display on Report
Give me Suitable Solution.

Thnx In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Links in the Database Expert are cleared. by clearing the links the data should be returned independently of each other. i.e There will always be the image data even if there is no report data.

If the tables need to be linked then you must ensure that at least one row is returned in the actual report data table. For example, you can do this be returning a row of `null` values.